# How to monitor mouse event when it moves out of the Android device screen?

Tags: android, screen, mouse, out

My Android app wants to track the external mouse movement(either Bluetooth mouse or USB mouse).

I wrote a customized View to monitor the mouse events, but the events stop producing when mouse moves to the edge of the screen. I can understand that in most cases, there is no need to track the movement which occurs outside of the device screen. But I do need to monitor that kind of mouse movement.

I guess it can be monitored by the low level API. But can anyone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well... how about that you got the key event when user input the bank password......

You may not get the key event if your activity or service not active but you may hijack the event from low level.

You can first change the /dev/input/eventX r/w value since all the event comes here, i.e. all the input event.
then you need write an C program e.g. to a dynamic library to select or epoll the event.
finally you can implement a JNI API to get the event from your apps.

Here we are.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Looks the Android device needs to be rooted before reading/writing /dev/input/eventX, right? That is not allowed in my use case.

Comment: Yes. if all apps can do that which means the world is not safe anymore...